# Enabling a CORS Response Filter in Tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, tomcat, cors

I am attempting to call a web service on one server from another (cross origin) using a fairly basic `jQuery.ajax` POST request.

```
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://dev.hostname.com/ws/account/example1@example.com?property_id=1&custnum=123456",
            dataType:"json"
        });
```

I am always getting the following `error` response ...

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://dev.hostname.com/ws/account/example1@example.com?property_id=1&custnum=123456.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin `http://localhost:63342` is therefore not allowed
>   access.

The web service is a Java-built Jersey based web service hosted on `Apache Tomcat/8.0.8`. I have tried sending the request as JSONP but that ran me into issues when attempting to handle the callbacks from the promise object. That's another post however ... As an alternative I decided to look into implementing a CORS Response solution. Now I am VERY new to Java programming and am not that comfortable with it so please bear with me.

I have looked at two primary solutions for implementing CORS. One is to build a custom response filter. I could not get that to work but then discovered that since Tomcat 7.0 a filter is supposedly already provided. I have seen several posts on this second solution but had absolutely no luck with it. Using the guidelines provided in the [Apache Tomcat Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) I added the following FILTER information to the web.xml file of the application (I have also tried adding it to the web.xml of the root and it didn't work there either).

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Last-Modified</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Since I am using `Tomcat 8.0.8`. I would have expected this to work, yet I continue to get the same error. Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATED**

I am adding the headers from Firebug when calling the service in Firefox. This is the Request header ...

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  0
Host    dev.hostname.com
Origin  http://localhost:63342
Pragma  no-cache
Referer http://localhost:63342/keurig/default.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
```

This is the Response header

```
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/plain
Date    Thu, 21 Aug 2014 17:50:58 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

I definitely do not see any of the "Access-Control-*" headers that would expect to be see in the response.

Comment: Try with the most minimal setup first, without adding any of the init-params so everything is left default. See if that works, then go from there adding in the other configuration properties until it stops working. I have it working with the minimal setup on Tomcat 7.

Comment: Thanks for the response Gimby ... unfortunately no change. Is there something else I could be overlooking? Do I have to have something configured or installed somewhere else in order for it to pay attention to the config file. The reason why I ask is because I have tried every combination of configurations I could think of and ALWAYS get the EXACT same response. I would have expected SOME sort of change in error behavior; a new error or something. I actually double-checked at one point to make sure that I was tweaking the correct server!

Comment: Well time to stop guessing and time to start using a HTTP sniffer to see what is actually being sent back and forth.

Comment: Added network information from Chrome to the original post.

Comment: Changed it with headers as reported in Firebug instead ...

Comment: Have you checked http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/ ?

Comment: I'm stumped. The only thing I do slightly different is to map the filter to /REST/* since that's the pattern I mapped to my JAX-RS service. What is the METHOD of that request that is made? Is it an OPTIONS request?

Comment: I should have added this to my original post ... this particular instance is a POST request ... I am wondering if there is a library that may be missing from my Tomcat installation for some reason that is required to support this filter? Kind of grasping at straws but since it seems to ignore this filter config it may be that that feature did not get installed with My Tomcat <shrugs> ...

Comment: I have excatly the same problem, have you sorted it out?

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis A colleague of mine worked this out, although I am not sure what he did that was different than what was already there. When I get a few minutes I will see if I can post the resolution ... if I can figure it out myself. Sorry that this may not be in time to help you out though. :(

Comment: @GaryO.Stenstrom how were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 4):

The CORS configuration provided here worked for me, but not until I had removed the space in 'Allowed Headers' after the comma in the last header.

> `<param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Last-Modified</param-value>`

Once I took out that space before "Last-Modified" I was in business.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that fixed this issue in a legacy Struts 2 application running Apache Tomcat/8.0.43 was to add the CORS Filter before the Struts 2 filter in the `web.xml` config file.